# Derived Classes with variable number of parameters

Tags: c++, function, derived-class

I have this specific class structure in my project (C++11 using Visual Studio 2013 for Windows) consisting of a base experiment class and many experiments (derived classes from the base experiment class). Each experiment has different number of parameters (4 to 12 parameters). In each experiment, the user provides certain initial values for the parameters and a unique set of equations for the data points collected (around 100 points) optimize these parameters. Now the user has an option of telling the program that a particular parameter/s should be fixed and not optimized. For example, experiment#1 has 7 parameters, the user can select that Parameter#1 and Parameter#5 are fixed and the remaining need to be optimized.

```
class Experiment1:public BaseExperiment{
public:
       Experiment1(){}
       virtual ~Experiment1(){}

private:
       double parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter6, parameter7;
}

class Experiment1Case1: public Experiment1{
public:
       Experiment1Case1(double x, double y)
       : x_(x), y_(y) {}

       template <typename T> bool operator()(const T* const parameter2, const T* const parameter3, const T* const parameter4, const T* const parameter6, const T* const parameter7, T* residual) const{
      // equation relating all parameters
  residual[0] = - T(y) + parameter2[0] + parameter3[0] *    sin(parameter6[0])/ parameter1Fixed; //long equation here
            return true;
        }

        void setparameter1(double initialParameter1) { parameter1Fixed = initialparameter1; }
        void setparameter5(double initialParameter5) { parameter5Fixed = initialparameter5; }

private:
   const double x_;
   const double y_;
   double parameter1Fixed, parameter5Fixed;
};
```

In my main program, depending on which parameters the user fixes, I have to call the specific function with the number of parameters that are not fixed. So for this example above, if the user fixes parameter1 and parameter5 then the code will be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < data1.size(); ++i) {
     Experiment1Case1 *exp1C1 = new Experiment1Case1(data1[i], data2[i]);
     exp1C1->setparameter1(20.0);
     exp1C1->setparameter5(290.0);
     problem.AddResidualBlock(new AutoDiffCostFunction<Experiment1Case1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,>(exp1C1), NULL, &parameter2, &parameter3, &parameter4, &parameter6, &parameter7);
}
```

So based on the parameters the user fixes, so 7 parameters (2 power 7) that is 128 combinations.Now my question is: is there a way I can provide this option and avoid declaring 128 different derived classes for a particular experiment and the project has n number of experiments.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are the parameters always of type `double`?

Comment: Are there 128 hand-crafted expressions, or is there a single 7-ary expression from which all restricted versions are derived?

Comment: The private variables in the base class are not accessible to derived classes

Comment: Yes all the parameters are always of type double.

Comment: @Kerrek SB There is a single 7-ary expression from which all restricted versions are derived. It is basically a same set of equation of for each experiment, the only expression in the equation that changes is whether a particular parameter is fixed or not. A very simple example: For experiment1: y[i] = par1[i] + par2[i]/par3[i] - par4[i]*par4[i]. ('i' varying from 0 to number of data points collected. Now if par1 is fixed: y[i] = par1fixed +  par2[i]/par3[i] - par4[i]*par4[i]

Comment: I assume there is a reason why you can't just put 7 `if`s in your code to choose whether to take the fixed parameter or the optimized parameter?

Comment: Is all this significantly different from just `std::bind`?

Comment: @Chris Drew: 7 ifs will not solve the issue because for 7 parameters there are 128 combinations of parameters being either fixed or optimized (2 power 7). The only option I see is to define 127 derived classes for a particular experiment and there are many experiments with more parameters. It is not practical to have my project with thousands of derived classes, hence looking for a practical solution for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Only got 100 points?

Just make an array with 100 copies of the selected fixed parameters and run the optimization.
Advantage you can use the same function for all optimizations.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? I am looking for a way in which I can use the same function for all optimizations, but with the parameters either being fixed or optimized I am not sure how I can use the same function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, helped me figure out the solution. I now use const_cast to change from optimized to fixed solution.

Comment: I use a std::vector<std::pair>> to store the fixed parameters with the fixed value. Then in the template bool operator(), I check the presence of the parameters and if present: const_cast<T*>(parameter4)[0] = (T)LockParameters[i].second;